# Having a particular key in the registry apply to multiple conditions via the AppliesTo string value

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, registry

I have a key that needs the rules enforced by it to apply to multiple drives. Its value is currently set to `AppliesTo=C:` and I am wondering if there is a some way to use `AppliesTo` like `AppliesTo=C:, D:` (does not work but is meant to append two drives).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking about [creating shortcut menu handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/context-menu-handlers)? In that case, see [Getting Dynamic Behavior for Static Verbs by Using Advanced Query Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/context-menu-handlers#getting-dynamic-behavior-for-static-verbs-by-using-advanced-query-syntax).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'OR' keyword can be used to apply the rule enforced by a key to multiple cases in the `AppliesTo` string value.

Example: `AppliesTo=C: OR D:`